# How to pass params through hapijs middleware to the routers

Tags: router, middleware, hapi.js

```js
server.ext('onRequest', (request, reply) => {
    //here is a param AA
    const AA = 1234;
    return reply.continue();
});

server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    handler: (request, reply) => {
        //here i want to get param AA
        reply('test');
    };
});
```

how could i pass the params through middlerware to the router, like Params AA;

Answer (score 0):

From the docs use request.app object to store application data

- http://hapijs.com/api#request-properties

You can then access the object when inside your route handler.